# Predicting probabilities in Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, multilabel-classification, probability

I have 1000 number of inputs in a sample each ranging between 0-1 as shown:

```
array([[0.404, 0.417, 0.43 , ..., 0.425, 0.416, 0.404],
   [0.318, 0.295, 0.321, ..., 0.284, 0.305, 0.323],
   [0.205, 0.2  , 0.19 , ..., 0.197, 0.203, 0.193],
   ...,
   [0.421, 0.44 , 0.456, ..., 0.452, 0.453, 0.432],
   [0.225, 0.239, 0.218, ..., 0.227, 0.226, 0.243],
   [0.439, 0.451, 0.427, ..., 0.417, 0.445, 0.47 ]])
```

and 1000 number of outputs in each sample as the probability distribution as follows:

```
array([[3.58779547e-03, 1.00498472e-04, 1.40697861e-04, ...,
    2.09036823e-03, 1.20598167e-03, 2.86420646e-03],
   [3.38713450e-03, 8.42105263e-05, 1.87134503e-05, ...,
    2.08654971e-03, 1.34736842e-03, 2.59181287e-03],
   [2.80166980e-03, 9.33889932e-06, 9.33889932e-06, ...,
    1.04595672e-03, 2.52150282e-03, 2.76431420e-03],
   ...,
   [4.77871131e-03, 4.16445430e-05, 1.00000000e-09, ...,
    2.91511801e-04, 1.07234698e-03, 2.47785031e-03],
   [3.39823659e-03, 1.00000000e-09, 1.00000000e-09, ...,
    2.31447465e-03, 1.50624541e-03, 2.59000735e-03],
   [4.37774882e-03, 2.03616224e-05, 1.00000000e-09, ...,
    3.15605147e-04, 2.43321388e-03, 2.63683010e-03]])
```

And I want to predict these probabilities bases on the inputs provided.

I treated this as a multi-classification problem with 1000 categories, each having its respective probabilities. But the error is 5.8 (cross-entropy).

I am using a NN with 2048 nodes and 3 layers with a 'softmax' activation function.
My loss function is 'categorical_crossentropy' and Adam(lr = 0.001) optimizer.

```
early_stopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(
min_delta=0.0001, # minimium amount of change to count as an improvement
patience=20, # how many epochs to wait before stopping
restore_best_weights=True,
)

model = keras.Sequential([
layers.Dense(2048, activation='softmax', input_shape=[1000]),

layers.Dense (units = 2048, activation = 'softmax'),

layers.Dense (units = 2048, activation = 'softmax'),

layers.Dense (units = 1000, activation = 'softmax'),
])

model.compile (keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001),
          loss = 'categorical_crossentropy')

history = model.fit(
x_norm_train, y_train,
validation_data=(x_norm_val, y_validation),
batch_size=23,
epochs=500,
callbacks=[early_stopping], # put your callbacks in a list
verbose=0,  # turn off training log
)
```

[image]

I have replaced the perfect 0.0 probability with 1e-9 in the output, which reduces the errors even further, but I am not getting good results yet.

Any suggestion would help me a lot. I have recently started ML, and I don't even know how I am using the NN is viable. Please help.

Comment: What is the input's shape ? I mean, you have 1000 rows, but how many columns (=features) do you have? It is an important question because you should have enough rows according to the quantity of features. For instance, if you have 1000 features, 1000 rows may not be enough to make good predictions.

Comment: @NicolasMartin Okay, this is indeed my problem. What should be the good ratio? I mean, I can reduce it to 125 features (columns), but how many data sets (rows) should I generate for this. I know this varies from problem to problem, but any estimate if you can give?

Comment: It highligh depends on the data's variability. The best solution is to start with a few features (3 or 4 - the most representative ones), check if the result is correct and then increase progressively (10, 20, 50, etc.). For 1000 rows, it should work well with 6 features max. In some cases, you can do a correlation heatmap to remove uncorrelated features (arrond 0 = features that are too noisy or not representative of the whole data set), and to detect most correlated ones (in some cases you can remove the duplicates). Don't remove the anti correlated because it is a kind of correlation.

Comment: Actually, the ratio is based on the quantity of combinations you could have. If you have 100 features with many possible combinations, you would need millions of rows to learn from them with a big neural network and reach good predictions. But if you have 100 features with few combinations (which is generally not the case in most projects), 1000 rows is enough. Your neural network should have enough data to cover most combinations and be able to make good predictions.